# Embed a Power BI report in React JS to get report instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to embed a Power BI report in React JS and I would like to embed the report and get the report instance to work further with it. I am using Power BI react extension in react to embed the report but I keep getting an error that Cannot read property 'embed' of undefined.

Index.js

```
import { powerbi, models, embed } from "powerbi-client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function ReportBI() {
  let token ="abcExample";
  let embedUrlBi = "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed";
  let reportId = "ReportID";
  
  const embedConfig = {
    type: "report",
    id: reportId,
    embedUrl: embedUrlBi,
    accessToken: token,
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed
  };

  function test() {
    var embedContainer = document.getElementById("container");
    var report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, embedConfig);
    console.log(report);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    test();
  });
   
  return (
    <>
      <div id="container"></div>
      
    </>
  );
}

const element = <ReportBI />;

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Index.Html

```
<div id="root">
      <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to get instance of the report after embedding it to do other things with it. Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the new [powerbi-client-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client-react) library for embedding PowerBI entities in React applications

The "[getEmbeddedComponent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-client-react#embed-a-power-bi-report)" prop returns the instance of embedded PowerBI report

Comment: Thank you. I am using this library and it does embed the report correctly but I have a question, Can you please answer the following 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322743/save-power-bi-embedded-report-in-database-after-making-changes

Comment: It can be possible to get the callback report object without rendering the component?